# PHP: Remove array from multidimensional array click

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array where I need to delete data on mouseclick.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Whatever
        [contact1] => contact name
        [contactemail1] => some@email.com
        [contact2] => other contact name
        [contactemail2] => someother@email.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Whatever
        [contact1] => contact name
        [contactemail1] => some@email.com
        [contact2] => other contact name
        [contactemail2] => someother@email.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Whatever
        [contact1] => contact name
        [contactemail1] => some@email.com
        [contact2] => other contact name
        [contactemail2] => someother@email.com
    )

)
```

I have a foreach loop that shows the data for me

```
foreach($klantennaam as $val){
echo '<tr height="65">'; 
echo '<td valign="top" style="padding-right:25px;">'.$val["naam"].'</td>';
echo '<td valign="top" style="padding-right:25px;">'.$val["contact1"].'
echo '</tr>';
}
```

I want to place a button behind the form that deletes data from the array based on a value like `name`.

e.g. `<a href="delete_from_db.php">Delete</a>`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please specify your problem or what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to delete entries of a static php array or do you want to remove entries from a certain kind of data source?

Comment: Paul. I want to remove entries from the array but not the entire array

Answer (score 0):

You showed us PHP code (serverside), but mouse actions are tracked on client side via JavaScript.

Basically this array stops to exist when php compiles it and echoes back. Thus you can't interfere with it.

If you want to delete a table row after you got results page:

1. Give each row (`<td>`) a unique ID
2. Create a new column to place a link
3. At link specify `onClick` javascript event:

   `onClick="deleteRow( "rowUniqueID" )"; return false;`
4. Create javascript function deleteRow ( uniqueId )
5. Use jQuery to call `AJAX` request upon delete_from_db.php, passing trough `POST` or `GET` a uniqueID parameter.
6. Execute SQL statements according to your SQL sctructure.

   For eg. `"DELETE FROM tableEx WHERE id = ".$_POST['uniqueID];`

*Note that passing argument directly to query from variables are dangerous, this holds vulnerability to SQL injections.*

Then you can hide or completely remove this row using jQuery at AJAX onComplete callback event. Or alternatively you can just refresh the page, assuming that you fetch your data from database.

Comment: The problem is nog that I want to interfere with it. I want to be able to delete records that are in the array. If I just 'hide' a <td> then it is still in the db.

Comment: Thnx. If I do the "DELETE FROM *..." doesn't it remove the entire array?

Comment: First of all "array" is a data construct, database use tables.
You have array in PHP, when you write it's data to database, it's stored as table.

If you want delete all data from table use TRUNCATE instead, it will be much faster.

Comment: Qile. Thnx I'll check it out but I don't want to delete all the data from the array. Just a single array from a multidimensional array based on e.g. the name of a field.